# Transferring ListView selection from Page2 to Page1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a project that requires me to ask the user's country and phone number. The phone number part is working fine. By itself, the country part is also working fine. Considering this a 2-page project, I have a ListView in Page2.xaml that displays a list of all countries (data bound to a .cs file (class file) that has my ViewModel). In Page1.xaml, I have a textblock (and a textbox for phone number which we don't need to worry about) whose **tapped** property navigates to Page2 (and displays the list of country). I would like to know:

1. How I can take the selected item from the list (that is in Page2) and display it in the textblock (in Page1).
2. If there is a 1-page way to implement this, that is, if I can show the listview itself with something like a PlaceholderText (that says **Select your Country**) and when it is clicked, it opens the entire list of country. This is something similar to signing up for WhatsApp or Line, or services of that sort.

If there is a way to implement #2, please guide me to the right path.

FYI, for #1, I tried to implement the local storage by putting

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localsetting = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
lstv_countries.SelectedItem = localsetting.Values["Countries"].ToString();
```

in the ItemsSelection event of the ListView (Page2) and then

```
 
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localsetting = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localsetting.Values["Countries"] = testText.Text;
```

in the GotFocus event of the textblock (in Page1). This doesn't work :(

Your response is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combobox control to achive the same thing without all the fuss.

Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780616.aspx

**EDIT**
In response to your comment, here is what I'd suggest you do:

In the NavigatedTo section set this:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        int x;
        if (int.TryParse(e.Parameter.ToString(), out x))
        {
            textText.Text=CountryList[x].Name
        }
        else
        {
            textText.Text="--Select your Country--";
        }
    }
```

In your page2 set this in your selectionchanged event handler

```
Frame.Navigate( typeof( Page1),Listview.SelectedIndex );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I would like to make use of the SemanticZoom feature. That's why I am keen on using that. What do you suggest?

Comment: If you insist on using the same methods then best way to keep the data available through pages is to create a static variable in App.xaml.cs file. Update it when selection is made in page 2 and use it in page 1

Comment: I used this logic in the SelectionChanged event of the ListView - 
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localsettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer container = localsettings.CreateContainer("Countries", Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
if (localsettings.Containers.ContainsKey("Countries"))
{
 lstv_countries.SelectedItem = localsettings.Containers["Countries"].Values["Countries"];
}
App.Global_Variable = (string)lstv_countries.SelectedItem;

As you said Global_Variable is a static variable in App.cs

Comment: In GotFocus event of the Textblock in Page1, I put this:

Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localsettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
bool hasContainer = localsettings.Containers.ContainsKey("Countries");
bool hasSettings = false;
if (hasContainer)
{hasSettings = localsettings.Containers["Countries"].Values.ContainsKey("Countries");}
testText.Text = localsettings.Containers["Countries"].Values.ContainsKey("Countries").ToString();

It still won't accept the selected item. What do you suggest? :(

Comment: Are you sure this textblock.gotfocus event is fired when you nevigate back to page 1?

Comment: It is from my understanding, yes. Plus, there is no other property that may get fired when I move back to it. Not that I could find. Do you suggest any other control, or any other logic, for that matter? I have looked all over but haven't found anything.

Comment: One other reason why it MAY NOT be working is because the textblock will get the focus anyway, as it is the first page to load (at least this is my understanding). PLUS, the tap event of that is wired to the page2, that displays the list of countries. I am not sure if that will override the focus event, when it goes BACK to Page1 after the country is selected. I am not thinking right probably. How do I take care of this!?

Comment: Is there a way I can use a ContentDialogue in this regards? I am not sure if that will help though..

Comment: By setting the FullSizeDesired property on the ContentDialog to True, I am getting the desired layout, but my ListView still isn't displaying there, despite of enclosing it within <ContentDialog x:Name="test"><!----></ContentDialog> and setting all the data bound property of the ListView like before.

Comment: Nope. Textblock.focus will not be fired when you nevigate back to page 1. To test it put a breakpoint in focus event handler and check if it hits when you nevigate back. Also I still recommend using the combobox for this case. No one is going to zoom in or zoom out in a list view. Better give them what they expect.

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestion. The main reason I need the ListView with semantic zoom is because of the number of countries there are, almost 194, if I am not mistaken. If he's from, say, India i wouldn't want him to scroll all the way down to India. If I have the semanticzoom available, i could simply have him activate the jump list and go to 'I' then select India from there. On the same lines, imagine he's from Zimbabwe!